# Can I create a dynamic graduate student dashboard with CiviCRM?

Tags: wordpress, registration, user-dashboard

I just recently heard of CiviCRM. My organization provides graduate students with scholarships for tuition, upkeep, etc. We want to create a platform where a graduate student can create an account and request money to be released for let's say payment of tuition. The request should generate a pdf and after approval update their dashboard with the new amount available to the student. Is this something that can be done with CiviCRM on Wordpress? We're currently using Ultimate member plugin and elementor pro to design the dashboard, with custom fields displaying user data on the dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

See if civigrant suits your needs: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/grants/what-is-civigrant/